# Modify value in data table UserProfile using function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to run .save() to change the value of a user model field.

Here is my code:

Views.py:

```
def traffic_task(request):
    tasks_traffic = Task.objects.filter(category="traffic")
    random_task = random.choice(tasks_traffic)
    task_id = random_task.pk
    user = request.user
    user.userprofile.daily_task = task_id
    user.save()
    return task_detail(request=request, pk=task_id)
```

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    daily_task = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    daily_task_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    daily_task_done_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2))
```

They are in two different apps so maybe it's an import missing?

Comment: You should save the `userprofile`, not the `user`. Furthermore it looks like `daily_task` should be a `ForeignKey`, to `Task`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped :)
The daily_task is just a reference to which task the user will render for the day.

Answer (score 2):

You should save the `UserProfile` object, not the `User` object, so something like:

```
def traffic_task(request):
    tasks_traffic = Task.objects.filter(category="traffic")
    random_task = random.choice(tasks_traffic)
    task_id = random_task.pk
    userprofile = request.user.userprofile
    userprofile.daily_task = task_id
    # perhaps you want to set daily_task_done to False here
    userprofile.save()
    return task_detail(request=request, pk=task_id)
```

Furthermore based on the code you provide, it looks like you want to add a `ForeignKey` to `Task`, it is better *not* to save the value of the primary key, since the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, etc. are not enforced:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    daily_task = models.ForeignKey('someapp.Task', null=True, default=None)
    daily_task_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    daily_task_done_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2))
```

Then you can use a `Task` object, like:

```
def traffic_task(request):
    tasks_traffic = Task.objects.filter(category="traffic")
    random_task = random.choice(tasks_traffic)
    userprofile = request.user.userprofile
    userprofile.daily_task = random_task
    userprofile.save()
    return task_detail(request=request, pk=task_id)
```

This thus creates extra validation, but it is also more convenient to work with the `Task` object, and in case you want to obtain the `Task`s "in bulk", one can use `.select_related(..)`, or `.prefetch_related(..)` (although one can do this with an `IntegerField` as well, it will require extra logic, and thus is less elegant).